# Configuring the Notification Gateway

Tags: virtocommerce

I have configured SendGrid to send email for the platform. Despite this the mail is still trying to be sent using the DefaultSmtpEmailNotificationSendingGateway.

I found this code in the VirtoCommerce.Platform.Web project, StartUp.cs.

```
        var emailNotificationSendingGatewayName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValue("VirtoCommerce:Notifications:Gateway", "Default");

        if (string.Equals(emailNotificationSendingGatewayName, "Default", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            emailNotificationSendingGateway = new DefaultSmtpEmailNotificationSendingGateway(settingsManager);
        }
        else if (string.Equals(emailNotificationSendingGatewayName, "SendGrid", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            emailNotificationSendingGateway = new SendGridEmailNotificationSendingGateway(settingsManager);
        }

        if (emailNotificationSendingGateway != null)
        {
            container.RegisterInstance(emailNotificationSendingGateway);
        }
```

Based on that I've tried.

1. Setting the app setting to "SendGrid" in the Azure AppService to override.
2. Then removing the default app setting from the web.config.
3. Then adding an explicit setting to "SendGrid" in the web.config.
4. Then removing the app setting from the Azure AppService

Despite this the mails are still routing to the DefaultSmtpEmailNotificationSendingGateway in the four states above.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When I set VirtoCommerce:Notifications:Gateway app setting to SendGrid, SendGridEmailNotificationSendingGateway start working. Proof: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AjdiiSHPnh4lvBVwGge87XP9eNGQ Which versions of platform & storefront you use?

Comment: @AleksandrVishnyakov Platform 2.13.14, Storefront 2.21.8.0 Does the setting need to be set both in the storefront and the platform?

Comment: No, only platform

Comment: Did you make any changes in platform?

Comment: No more than configuration changes. Looking into cleaning up the deploy since this makes no sense. My dev instance is using the SendGrid but after blowing away the app_data folder I'm trying to work through getting modules installed getting their assemblies back into the modules folder.